# Why does my pixi.js displacement map go black when I replace it?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Here is the code I use to insert it. It works fine with a map I snatched from a codepen example, but when I create my own .png, slightly larger, the screen-space with the original image, and the displacement map goes black. What am I doing wrong?

```js
  const createRipple = () => {
  const sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(PIXI.loader.resources['map2.png'].texture);
  sprite.anchor.set(0.5);
  sprite.scale.set(2);
  stage.addChild(sprite);

  const filter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(sprite);

  stage.filters = [filter];

  return {
    update: () => {
      const mouse = renderer.plugins.interaction.mouse.global;
      sprite.position.x = mouse.x;
      sprite.position.y = mouse.y;

      // center canvas inside #main
      $('canvas').css('margin-left', ($('#main').width() - $('canvas').width())/2)
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the dimensions of your PNG file? It may not work unless the [dimensions are a power of 2](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter.html).